# How to to fix legend colors with x_bins in seaborn regplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

Seaborn regplot stops matching legend color to line color when I include x_bins in the parameters. It works fine until I add x_bins and then the multi-colored legend loses its color differentiation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data=pd.DataFrame({"VarX" : np.arange(10), 
                   'VarY1': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY2': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY3': np.random.rand(10)})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY1', data=data, x_bins=10)
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY2', data=data, x_bins=10)
sns.regplot(x='VarX', y='VarY3', data=data, x_bins=10)
fig.legend(labels=['First','Second','Third'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn has its own concept of legend which often conflicts with default matplotlib legends.

To stay in the seaborn way of thinking, you can use `lmplot` for this and let it automatically produce the legend. This requires to reshape the input data a bit.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd


data=pd.DataFrame({"VarX" : np.arange(10), 
                   'VarY1': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY2': np.random.rand(10),
                   'VarY3': np.random.rand(10)})

df = data.set_index("VarX")
df.columns = ['First','Second','Third']
df = df.stack().rename_axis(['VarX','Ycategory']).rename('VarY').reset_index()


sns.lmplot(x="VarX", y="VarY", hue="Ycategory", data = df, x_bins=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I find it unsatisfying--I feel we should not have to reshape the data to plot multiple columns of data in one figure. I'll search for other options.

Comment: Sure, it's always good to be doubtful; at the end you may not find a better solution, but many which are worse, and hence will have learned a lot about the problem.